# CFQuery performance difference?

Tags: coldfusion-9

Is there any performance difference in using ColdFusion query like this -

```
<cfquery name="myquery" datasouce="#dsn#" username="#username#" password="#password#">
     SELECT * FROM mytable
</cfquery>
```

or

```
    <cfquery name="myquery" datasouce="#dsn#" >
         SELECT * FROM mytable
    </cfquery>
```

where datasource is defined in coldfusion administrator.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, there are no mandatory username / password attributes for the data source from ColdFusion 9 onwards. We just need to set that up in the CFAdmin and refer only to the data source in the code as in your latter example. In all pre-9 ColdFusion application we are used to used passing username and password via the CFQuery tag traditionally, this is more of a forced change than anything else related to performance.

Like in Oracle we will often have many applications using the same database (and thus that can use the same datasource) but based on the login, will use a separate schema in that database. Having to set up datasources for every application is not really something we want to have to do. 
ColdFusion 9.01 allows us to set the datasource using a struct that includes the username/password.